# display Android Toast success/unsuccessful message

Tags: java, android, toast

my app below copies a file from the raw folder to the allocated location written in the code, What i want to do is display a toast message stating whether the file has been successfully written or whether it has failed.

What code is needed and where would i place it within my existing code cheers guy's.

```
public class TrialActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    runDialog(5);
}

private void runDialog(final int seconds)
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...", "unpacking patch in progress");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramView)
      {

      }

   {

              InputStream in = null;
              OutputStream out = null;
  String filename="savegame.bin";           
  try {    

                in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.savegame);
                out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/data/com.glu.android.brawler/files/" + filename);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
              } catch(Exception e) {
                  Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                  Message message = Message.obtain();      
                  message.what = 1;               
                  mHandler.sendMessage(message);
              }       

      }
      private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int read;
          while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);

            Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage( Message msg ) 
                {  
                    Toast toast;
                        switch(msg.what) 
                        {          
                           case 1: // for success
                               toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File has been successfully written.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                               toast.show();
                           break;
                           case 0: // for Error
                               toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occur during writting file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                               toast.show();
                           break;

                       }
               };
            };

          }
      }
      }
    );


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using **Handler** in your code.

You should pass the message to handler what you need to display on OS....like below...

```
Message message = Message.obtain();      
message.what = 1;  // success message               
mHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

& show Toast in your handler based on that message...

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
     public void handleMessage( Message msg ) 
     {  
         Toast toast;
             switch(msg.what) 
             {          
                case 1: // for success
                    toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File has been successfully written.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                break;
                case 0: // for Error
                    toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occur during writting file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                break:

            }
    }
```

}

Comment: In your case you need to pass the success message to handler when your file copied successfully...& pass the error message when any exception occurs....

Comment: Thank you very much this as helped a lot, I have been looking for this solution cheers "Priyank"

Comment: Yeah sure no worries, Just one issue i keep getting "mHandler cannot be resolved" ?

Comment: ok...where are you put handler in your code ?...& from where you pass message ?

Comment: Ive updated my question to show you my code with the pass message and handler implemented.

Comment: You need to remove handler from copyFile() function & put it directly in your activity...not in any function...

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the Handler class, calling a handler at the end of your thread.

But personnaly I would opt for the AsyncTask class.
This class allows you to work on threads and after the thread is finished, you can make changes to the UI.

Read up on it on the Android Developers Website.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void runDialog(final int seconds)
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...", "patch is being prepared");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                                 Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                   }});
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramView)
      {

      }

   {
```