# Display success message after file is copied

Tags: java, android, toast

I am fairly new to Android development so I thought I would start off with a basic app. When a button is pressed, it copies a file to the location written in the code (see my code below). When I press the install button and the file is copied to its location, I want a toast message to display "Successfully Installed or Error while copying file". How would I implement this?

```
public class TrialActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    runDialog(5);
}

private void runDialog(final int seconds)
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...", "unpacking patch in progress");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramView)
      {

      }

   {

              InputStream in = null;
              OutputStream out = null;
  String filename="savegame.bin";           
  try {    

                in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.savegame);
                out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/data/files/" + filename);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
              } catch(Exception e) {
                  Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
              }       

      }
      private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int read;
          while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);


          }
      }
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406106/display-android-toast-success-unsuccessful-message/12406455#12406455

Comment: You have completely lost control of your braces `{}`... You have two copy methods, both of which are inside your `OnClickListener`, but not a part of the `onClick()` method... Anyway, when you are done coping a file just compare the size of the original and the copied file.

Answer (score 1):

use next code:

```
    private class AsyncTaskDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Toast toastSuccess;


    boolean flagSuccessCopy =false;
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


                }
            }

            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                copyFiles();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result); 

              if (getActivity() != null) {
                 if(flagSuccessCopy){
                  toastSuccess  = Toast.makeText(context, "Success", duration);
                 }else{
                      toastSuccess  = Toast.makeText(context, "Error", duration);
                 }
                toast.show();               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a description of your code and _why_ the question's author should use it.

Comment: author want copy files and get message about success copy files or not success, because  better used AsyncTask for copy in background. I'm on place author added progress dialog in time copy files for users.

Comment: Or for copy files create service and call him when necessary. May be perhaps Comand if necessary copy many files to different places, and not all at once. It's only my view

Comment: Sounds good to me. In the future please try to add a brief description to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Allows to copy any file from any application to SD card

```
import ru.gelin.android.sendtosd.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProgressDialog extends AlertDialog implements Progress {

/** Activity for which the dialog is created */

Activity activity;

/** Progress manager for the dialog */
ProgressManager manager = new ProgressManager();

/**
 *  Creates the customized progress dialog for
 *  activity.
 */
protected ProgressDialog(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
}

@Override
public void setFiles(int files) {
    synchronized (manager) {
        manager.setFiles(files);
    }
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (manager) {
                updateTotalProgress();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void nextFile(final File file) {
    synchronized (manager) {
        manager.nextFile(file);
    }
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (manager) {
                updateFileName(file);
                updateFileProgress();
                updateTotalProgress();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void processBytes(long bytes) {
    synchronized (manager) {
        manager.processBytes(bytes);
    }
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (manager) {
                updateFileProgress();
            }
        }
    });
}

void updateTotalProgress() {
    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.total_progress);
    progress.setMax(manager.getFiles());
    progress.setProgress(manager.getFile());
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_files);
    text.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.files_progress,
            manager.getFile(), manager.getFiles()));
}

void updateFileName(File file) {
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }
    TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    view.setText(file.getName());
}

void updateFileProgress() {
    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.file_progress);
    if (manager.getProgressInUnits() < 0) {
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    } else {
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setMax((int)(manager.getSizeInUnits() * 10));
        progress.setProgress((int)(manager.getProgressInUnits() * 10));
    }
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_size);
    text.setText(getContext().getString(manager.getSizeUnit().progressString,
            manager.getProgressInUnits(), manager.getSizeInUnits()));
    }

}
```

source: http://code.google.com/p/sendtosd-android/source/browse/src/ru/gelin/android/sendtosd/progress/ProgressDialog.java?spec=svn0933973391a12bee4759a32f5776864c64022d71&r=0933973391a12bee4759a32f5776864c64022d71